# Dynamic text changes position of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span which has a predefined value which is initiated on page load.
The user can alter the values by interacting with an input field. 
My problem is that all the spans are in a table, and whenever the number is altered 
instead of appearing in the exact same spot as the predefined number, it positions itself up like 20px or so.

Any help will be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<table class="tbl1">
    <tr>
        <td style="overflow: hidden; width: 280px; text-align: left; valign: top"><span class="Cs boxGreen">A</span>
        </td>
        <td width="18%"><span class="number1Output"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var currency = "£";

(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.number1Output').html($('#number1').val());
    });
});

function displayNumber(value, id, id2) {
    var output = '.' + id + "Output";
    if (value == 0) {
        $(output).html('');
        $(id2).html("free");
    } else {
        $(output).html('+' + value + currency + '&nbsp;');
        $(id2).html(value + currency);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your codes

Comment: Your script seems incomplete, what is `currency`?

Comment: sorry I reedited it just a string "£".

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the width of a span/field/window/etc. and the positioning does not look right you might want to use CSS.  **min-width** can help with this.